# Comic book about guys with powers that are hunted by society

Tags: story-identification, comics

There was a comic book I had, but I can’t remember the name. I don’t remember the name of the publisher, but wasn’t something like Marvel/DC/Vertigo, was some smaller one. Also, it was published somewhere between 2006~2008.

The plot was about some people that had powers (can’t remember the source, but was either genetic, or came from experiments), that at some point started to be hunted by the government. Some of them helped the government, and others went rogue. I just had the first issue, but the story was centered on one guy that somehow had a way to track other mutants in his DNA (more about him below). And a bunch of people were interested on him.

Some characters I can remember:

- The guy I mentioned before: His parents had superpowers, and somehow put on his body (DNA, I think), some stuff that had info on all other guys that had powers too. His power is that he replicates the powers from any other mutant near him (he doesn’t seem to be able to control it). His parents didn’t allow him to go to the city, and he didn’t know anything about him or his parents having some sort of powers, also, his mother made him take pills for radiation poisoning everyday.
- A girl who could shoot plasma with a gun: She had some weird uncontrollable power, that was contained when she was with a special gun (that was like a pistol). That gun could shot energy beams that her power created.
- An Assassin that could become invisible.
- Some guy that could do short blinks.

I just had one comic, and was the first issue, but here’s what I can remember from the whole story:

There’s a short scene at a cafe, where the guy that can become invisible goes there to kill another “mutant”. The target was a person that killed normal humans (and consumed something from them), and would assume their appearance (his/her real form was a monstrosity). In their talk, they mention something about them being have some level/class of threat (something like “class/grade A Assassin “). The guy easily kills the thing.

Next scene is at the house of the guy who can replicate powers from other “mutants”. He lives isolated from the city, and is talking with his parents (complaining why his mother has to cut his hair, instead of him going to a barbershop at town). During this talk, it is implied that he can unconsciously take precautions for things that will happen in a near future (he says many examples, but the one I remember is one of him having a book teaching CPR, when someone else had a heart attack, and this allowed him to save the guy).

The scene goes back to the cafe, a group from the government, lead by the girl who can shoot plasma beams, gets there too late (it’s explained that the creature killed by the Assassin, had some info about some device that could track all “mutants”, that’s the reason the Assassin killed it). But according to the girl, the brain is still active a few hours after it's killed, so she picks up the creature’s head, and gives it to another mutant (that probably can read minds if he touches the person who will be read).

The scene goes back to the house of the guy with his parents, and he goes and take a pill of iodine, and their parents get nervous, and lock him in the basement of the house. A bunch of soldiers appear, his mom explodes herself (a mini nuclear bomb), while the husband is covered in some spiky thing, and keeps killing the soldiers that survived (the explanation is that him taking the pills announced to his parents that the mother would need to explode). While his father is on a rampage, he leaves the debris from the house (without a scratch), this makes his dad angry (he wanted to hide him from the government, his wife killed herself, and he just appeared in front of everyone. He tries to sacrifice his son, but the guy replicates his dad’s power(unintentionally), and kills dad (unintentionally too). After that he starts to cry confused, and he takes a tranquilizer shot from the girl that can shoot energy beams.

Can’t remember more that that, only that there are a bunch of people trying to kill/capture the guy.

Comment: Welcome to SFF! Can you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question/9337#9337) and [edit] in anything else you may remember? Were there any specific plot elements that were memorable? You also use the term mutants but I believe that is a X-Men related term "only". Are you sure it wasn't a story from them?

Comment: No, it wasn’t x-men, was something that had no relation to any big comic universe. But I will edit what I can remember from the comic.

Comment: Hrm. Haven't read it in long enough that I can't tell if this matches or not, but the first tings I thought about were *Supreme Power* (published by Marvel, but under their "Max" imprint), and *Rising Stars*. Both were by J. Michael Straczynski.

Comment: I remembered, it was Hunter Killer. I checked this Rising Stars, and I remembered the publisher (top cow). Somehow this helped me find the comic. Thank you very much

Comment: If you have found the answer, please post it as such and mark it "accepted" after 24 hours, so other people who are looking for this comic can find it more easily

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the OP comment above, this comic was "Hunter-Killer", number 1 of the Cyberforce series published by Top Cow.

Per the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hunter-Killer_(comics)) about the comic:

> During the Cold War, in response to the concern that a nuclear war
>   would destroy the world, the United States government began a project
>   to create living super-weapons. These beings were referred to as
>   "Ultra Sapiens". However, there was a breakout, and most of the **Ultra
>   Sapiens went underground, hiding their gifts**. **Some went back to work
>   for the government, tracking their rogue brethren** and dealing with
>   "situations" – they are the eponymous hunter-killers of the story.
>
> However, something else was also created by the project, capable of
>   tracking and neutralising any Ultra Sapiens, anywhere. No one knows
>   what it is, what it looks like, or where it is. However, **a married
>   couple in rural Montana might have some ideas, and their strangely
>   gifted twenty-year-old son** would be very surprised at the answer...
>
> As they soon find out, their son is the **long lost object created by
>   the project that could track the other Ultra Sapiens**, purposely named
>   the catalog...